# Split text string after 60 characters, To previous delimiter in batch

Tags: string, batch-file, text, token

Hello I want to split a text string stored in the variable called %text%, It is standard text, delimited by spaces. Every time it reaches 60 characters long, I would like to split it at it's previous delim, and store it as a new line variable called %line1%, %line2%, %line3% and so on.

eg.

```
%text% This is an example text sting I am using for this demonstration, I would like this to be split when ever the text exceeds 60 characters.
```

This would become

```
%line1% This is an example text sting I am using for this  
%line2% demonstration, I would like this to be split when ever the  
%line3% text exceeds 60 characters.
```

Can anyone help? I was thinking about setting every word in the string as a token, but then im not sure how to get the lengths.

EDIT this is what i have been attempting

```
:epg

for /f "delims=" %%n in (%Apps%\epg\epg01.nfo) do set epg01=%%n
for /f "delims=" %%n in (%Apps%\epg\epg01.nfo) do set epg02=%%n
for /f "delims=" %%n in (%Apps%\epg\epgxx.nfo) do set epgxx=%%n
for /f "delims=" %%n in (%Apps%\epg\btm1.nfo) do set btm1=%%n
for /f "delims=" %%n in (%Apps%\epg\btm2.nfo) do set btm2=%%n
for /f "delims=" %%n in (%Apps%\epg\btm3.nfo) do set btm3=%%n
for /f "delims=" %%n in (%Apps%\epg\btm4.nfo) do set btm4=%%n
for /f "delims=" %%n in (%Apps%\epg\btm5.nfo) do set btm5=%%n
for /f "delims=" %%n in (%Apps%\epg\btm6.nfo) do set btm6=%%n
for /f "delims=" %%n in (%Apps%\epg\btm7.nfo) do set btm7=%%n
for /f "delims=" %%n in (%Apps%\epg\btm8.nfo) do set btm8=%%n
for /f "delims=" %%n in (%Apps%\epg\btm9.nfo) do set btm09=%%n
echo Paste in epg info now, It will be auto formatted into .nfo:
set /p info=
echo %info%>>%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo
%apps%\fnr --cl --find "-" --replace " " --dir "%temp%" --fileMask "%output%_info.nfo"



for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf1=%%i
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf2=%%i
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf3=%%i
for /f "tokens=4 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf4=%%i
for /f "tokens=5 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf5=%%i
for /f "tokens=6 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf6=%%i
for /f "tokens=7 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf7=%%i
for /f "tokens=8 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf8=%%i
for /f "tokens=9 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf9=%%i
for /f "tokens=10 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf10=%%i
for /f "tokens=11 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf11=%%i
for /f "tokens=12 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf12=%%i
for /f "tokens=13 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf13=%%i
for /f "tokens=14 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf14=%%i
for /f "tokens=15 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf15=%%i
for /f "tokens=16 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf16=%%i
for /f "tokens=17 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf17=%%i
for /f "tokens=18 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf18=%%i
for /f "tokens=19 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf19=%%i
for /f "tokens=20 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf20=%%i
for /f "tokens=21 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf21=%%i
for /f "tokens=22 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf22=%%i
for /f "tokens=23 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf23=%%i
for /f "tokens=24 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf24=%%i
for /f "tokens=25 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf25=%%i
for /f "tokens=26 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf26=%%i
for /f "tokens=27 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf27=%%i
for /f "tokens=28 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf28=%%i
for /f "tokens=29 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf29=%%i
for /f "tokens=30 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf30=%%i
for /f "tokens=31 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf31=%%i
for /f "tokens=32 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf32=%%i
for /f "tokens=33 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf33=%%i
for /f "tokens=34 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf34=%%i
for /f "tokens=35 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf35=%%i
for /f "tokens=36 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf36=%%i
for /f "tokens=37 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf37=%%i
for /f "tokens=38 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf38=%%i
for /f "tokens=39 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf39=%%i
for /f "tokens=40 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf40=%%i
for /f "tokens=41 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf41=%%i
for /f "tokens=42 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf42=%%i
for /f "tokens=43 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf43=%%i
for /f "tokens=44 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf44=%%i
for /f "tokens=45 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf45=%%i
for /f "tokens=46 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf46=%%i
for /f "tokens=47 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf47=%%i
for /f "tokens=48 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf48=%%i
for /f "tokens=49 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf49=%%i
for /f "tokens=50 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf50=%%i
for /f "tokens=51 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf51=%%i
for /f "tokens=52 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf52=%%i
for /f "tokens=53 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf53=%%i
for /f "tokens=54 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf54=%%i
for /f "tokens=55 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf55=%%i
for /f "tokens=56 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf56=%%i
for /f "tokens=57 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf57=%%i
for /f "tokens=58 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf58=%%i
for /f "tokens=59 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf59=%%i
for /f "tokens=60 delims= " %%i in (%Temp%\%output%_info.nfo) do set inf60=%%i

echo              %inf1%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf1.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf1.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf1=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf1% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf0 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf2.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf2.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf2=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf2% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf1 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf3.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf3.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf3=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf3% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf2 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf4.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf4.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf4=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf4% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf3 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf5.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf5.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf5=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf5% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf4 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf6.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf6.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf6=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf6% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf5 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf7.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf7.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf7=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf7% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf6 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7% %inf8%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf8.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf8.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf8=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf8% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf7 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7% %inf8% %inf9%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf9.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf9.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf9=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf9% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf8 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7% %inf8% %inf9% %inf10%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf10.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf10.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf10=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf10% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf9 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7% %inf8% %inf9% %inf10% %inf11%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf11.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf11.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf11=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf11% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf10 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7% %inf8% %inf9% %inf10% %inf11% %inf12%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf12.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf12.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf12=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf12% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf11 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7% %inf8% %inf9% %inf10% %inf11% %inf12% %inf13%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf13.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf13.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf13=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf13% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf12 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7% %inf8% %inf9% %inf10% %inf11% %inf12% %inf13% %inf14%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf14.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf14.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf14=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf14% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf13 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7% %inf8% %inf9% %inf10% %inf11% %inf12% %inf13% %inf14% %inf15%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf15.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf15.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf15=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf15% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf14 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7% %inf8% %inf9% %inf10% %inf11% %inf12% %inf13% %inf14% %inf15% %inf16%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf16.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf16.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf16=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf16% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf15 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7% %inf8% %inf9% %inf10% %inf11% %inf12% %inf13% %inf14% %inf15% %inf16% %inf17%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf17.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf17.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf17=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf17% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf16 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7% %inf8% %inf9% %inf10% %inf11% %inf12% %inf13% %inf14% %inf15% %inf16% %inf17% %inf18%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf18.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf18.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf18=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf18% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf17 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7% %inf8% %inf9% %inf10% %inf11% %inf12% %inf13% %inf14% %inf15% %inf16% %inf17% %inf18% %inf19%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf19.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf19.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf19=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf19% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf18 ) else ( echo checking next )
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7% %inf8% %inf9% %inf10% %inf11% %inf12% %inf13% %inf14% %inf15% %inf16% %inf17% %inf18% %inf19% %inf20%>>%Temp%\%output%_inf20.nfo
for %%? in (%Temp%\%output%_inf20.nfo) do ( set /A charsinf20=%%~z? - 2 )
if %charsinf20% GEQ 65 ( goto line1_inf19 ) else ( echo checking next )




:line1_inf0
echo im at line1_inf0 and charsinf1 is %charsinf1% characters long
pause
:line1_inf1
echo im at line1_inf1 and charsinf1 is %charsinf1% characters long
pause
:line1_inf2
echo im at line1_inf2 and charsinf2 is %charsinf2% characters long
pause
:line1_inf3
echo im at line1_inf3 and charsinf3 is %charsinf3% characters long
pause
:line1_inf4
echo im at line1_inf4 and charsinf4 is %charsinf4% characters long
pause
:line1_inf5
echo im at line1_inf5 and charsinf5 is %charsinf5% characters long
pause
:line1_inf6
echo im at line1_inf6 and charsinf6 is %charsinf6% characters long
pause
:line1_inf7
echo im at line1_inf7 and charsinf7 is %charsinf7% characters long
pause
:line1_inf8
echo im at line1_inf8 and charsinf8 is %charsinf8% characters long
pause



:line1_inf9
echo im at line1_inf9 and charsinf9 is %charsinf9% characters long
set /a maths=65 - %charsinf9%
for /f "delims=" %%n in (%Apps%\epg\btm%maths%.nfo) do set btm=%%n
echo              %inf1% %inf2% %inf3% %inf4% %inf5% %inf6% %inf7% %inf8% %inf9%%btm%
pause


:line1_inf10
echo im at line1_inf10 and charsinf10 is %charsinf10% characters long
pause
:line1_inf11
echo im at line1_inf11 and charsinf11 is %charsinf11% characters long
pause
:line1_inf12
echo im at line1_inf12 and charsinf12 is %charsinf12% characters long
pause
:line1_inf13
echo im at line1_inf13 and charsinf13 is %charsinf13% characters long
pause
:line1_inf14
echo im at line1_inf14 and charsinf14 is %charsinf14% characters long
pause
:line1_inf15
echo im at line1_inf15 and charsinf15 is %charsinf15% characters long
pause
:line1_inf16
echo im at line1_inf16 and charsinf16 is %charsinf16% characters long
pause
:line1_inf17
echo im at line1_inf17 and charsinf17 is %charsinf17% characters long
pause
:line1_inf18
echo im at line1_inf18 and charsinf18 is %charsinf18% characters long
pause
:line1_inf19
echo im at line1_inf19 and charsinf19 is %charsinf19% characters long
pause
```

Comment: hey aschipfl, I edited in what i have been trying, but like I was saying I think I was going down the wrong idea path,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script splits the line of text into words delimited by <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> and rebuilds new lines while checking the length when appending each single word:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_TEXT=This is an example text sting I am using for this demonstration, I would like this to be split when ever the text exceeds 60 characters."
set /A "_LEN=60"
set "_DELIM= " & if not defined _DELIM set "_DELIM= "

rem // Read file line by line:
set /A "NUM=0" & set "$COLLECT[0000000000]= "
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%_TEXT%") do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    rem // Split current line into delimited words:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for %%I in ("!LINE:%_DELIM%=" "!") do (
        endlocal
        set "ITEM=%%~I"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "IDX=0000000000!NUM!"
        for %%J in (!IDX:~-10!) do (
            rem // Attempt to rebuild the line string and check length:
            set "COLLECT=!$COLLECT[%%J]! !ITEM!"
            if "!COLLECT:~2!"=="!COLLECT:~2,%_LEN%!" (
                rem // Length limit not exceeded, so store rebuilt line:
                for /F "delims=" %%K in ("!COLLECT!") do (
                    endlocal
                    set "$COLLECT[%%J]=%%K"
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                )
            ) else (
                rem // Length limit exceeded, so begin a new line:
                set /A "NUM+=1"
                set "IDX=0000000000!NUM!"
                for %%J in (!IDX:~-10!) do (
                    for /F "delims=" %%K in ("  !ITEM!") do (
                        endlocal
                        set /A "NUM+=1" & set "$COLLECT[%%J]=%%K"
                        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    endlocal
)
rem // Return rebuilt lines:
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%K in ('2^> nul set $COLLECT[') do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!LINE:~2!
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Note that this approach fails when the text contains any of the following characters: `"`, `*`, `?`, `<` and `>`.
In case the input text contains multiple lines, they become concatenated.